# How to build using Bazel offline

Tags: bazel, jsonnet

I want to build my jsonnet with Bazel. For that I am using the jsonnet rules. Unfortunately in my build pipelines I can't pull from github. So, I have been reading into offline builds, but I can't seem to find a working solution. I have pulled the jsonnet rules repo and tried to build the jsonnet with

```
$ bazel test //project ----distdir=<jsonnet_rules_repo>
```

But this doesn't work. So, I was wondering if anyone knows the proper way to handle this?

Update:

This is the error message

```
> ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'jsonnet_go':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel/9246e2215e1e698b5691dcd295e999fc/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 177, column 30, in _git_repository_implementation
        update = _clone_or_update(ctx)
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel/9246e2215e1e698b5691dcd295e999fc/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 36, column 20, in _clone_or_update
        git_ = git_repo(ctx, directory)
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel/9246e2215e1e698b5691dcd295e999fc/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 91, column 12, in git_repo
        _update(ctx, git_repo)
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel/9246e2215e1e698b5691dcd295e999fc/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 103, column 10, in _update
        fetch(ctx, git_repo)
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel/9246e2215e1e698b5691dcd295e999fc/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 129, column 27, in fetch
        _git_maybe_shallow(
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel/9246e2215e1e698b5691dcd295e999fc/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 171, column 15, in _git_maybe_shallow
        _error(ctx.name, start + args_list, st.stderr)
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel/9246e2215e1e698b5691dcd295e999fc/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 182, column 9, in _error
        fail("error running '%s' while working with @%s:\n%s" % (command_text, name, stderr))
Error in fail: error running 'git fetch origin refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*' while working with @jsonnet_go:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/google/go-jsonnet/': Could not resolve host: github.com
ERROR: no such package '@jsonnet_go//bazel': error running 'git fetch origin refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*' while working with @jsonnet_go:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/google/go-jsonnet/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

I have also put the jsonnet repo in the distdir folder, but still getting this error.

Comment: What did you put in the `--distdir` directory? Did you specify its contents in your `WORKSPACE`? 

True to form, bazel documentation (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/external.html#offline-builds) is woefully inadequate, but they do point you to how they do it for the bazel distribution itself: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/5cfa0303d6ac3b5bd031ff60272ce80a704af8c2/WORKSPACE#L116

Comment: @JayEye I put everything of the jsonnet rules in the dist dir. But jsonnet rules also loads in packages, but that didn't get loaded in the dist dir. Didn't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a simple C++ project with bazel where I had to build it on our Jenkins Server which has no internet connection. Here my solution: [Build C++ project with Bazel offline (without internet connection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68104949/build-c-project-with-bazel-offline-without-internet-connection)