# Build C++ project with Bazel offline (without internet connection)

Tags: c++, build, bazel, offline

I try to build the Bazel C++ Build Tutorial from the Bazel homepage (Getting Started) with this command but without any connection to the internet: `bazel build //main:hello-world`

The Jenkins Server will not have any connection to the internet so I can't do prefetching or similar. Is there a way how to prepare my C++ project on another computer and transfer the dependencies to the Jenkins Server to do it offline? How? I would just need what I got from the following error message respectively get the tutorial running:

```
Extracting Bazel installation...
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Repository rules_cc instantiated at:
  /DEFAULT.WORKSPACE.SUFFIX:267:6: in <toplevel>
  C:/users/XXX/_bazel_XXX/dq2p42jq/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/utils.bzl:201:18: in maybe
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  C:/users/XXX/_bazel_XXX/dq2p42jq/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:336:31: in <toplevel>
WARNING: Download from https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d.zip failed: class java.io.IOException Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented"
WARNING: Download from https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d.zip failed: class java.io.IOException Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented"
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'rules_cc':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/XXX/_bazel_XXX/dq2p42jq/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl", line 111, column 45, in _http_archive_impl
                download_info = ctx.download_and_extract(
Error in download_and_extract: java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d.zip, https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d.zip] to C:/users/XXX/_bazel_XXX/dq2p42jq/external/rules_cc/temp1363696983472254851/b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d.zip: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented"
ERROR: Error fetching repository: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/XXX/_bazel_XXX/dq2p42jq/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl", line 111, column 45, in _http_archive_impl
                download_info = ctx.download_and_extract(
Error in download_and_extract: java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d.zip, https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d.zip] to C:/users/XXX/_bazel_XXX/dq2p42jq/external/rules_cc/temp1363696983472254851/b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d.zip: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented"
ERROR: Skipping '//main:hello-world': no such package '@rules_cc//cc': java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d.zip, https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d.zip] to C:/users/XXX/_bazel_XXX/dq2p42jq/external/rules_cc/temp1363696983472254851/b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d.zip: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented"
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: no such package '@rules_cc//cc': java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d.zip, https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d.zip] to C:/users/XXX/_bazel_XXX/dq2p42jq/external/rules_cc/temp1363696983472254851/b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d.zip: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented"
INFO: Elapsed time: 30.974s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
    currently loading: main
```

**Update**:
I tried prefetching and it doesn't work. What I did:

1. run `bazel fetch //...`
2. Copy the prefetched data from `bazel info output_base` directory from local to jenkins server (I had to recreate one sym link to the install dir).
3. I run `bazel build --fetch=false //main:hello-world` on jenkins without refatching. Now I get following error:

```
Loading: 
Loading: 0 packages loaded
WARNING: /DEFAULT.WORKSPACE:1:17: External repository 'bazel_tools' is not up-to-date and fetching is disabled. To update, run the build without the '--nofetch' command line option.
ERROR: error loading package '': Every .bzl file must have a corresponding package, but '@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl' does not have one. Please create a BUILD file in the same or any parent directory. Note that this BUILD file does not need to do anything except exist.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.298s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found one solution for offline building a simple C++ projects with bazel.
First you have to download the `rules_cc` and `rules_java` libs, because these where the external dependent libs in the simple Bazel C++ tutorial project. I found no release for `rules_cc` so I downloaded the zip file from the url which was mentioned in the error message on the console when I was trying to use bazel build offline: https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d.zip. The sha key was also mentioned in the error message when you try to use the lib locally with a wrong sha key (see below). The rules_java lib can be downloaded here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_java/releases. The `WORKSPACE` specification is also mentioned there.

Then you have to add the following to your `WORKSPACE` file. Be aware, that you have to point to your local copy of the archive files for `rules_cc` and `rules_java`. And for `rules_cc` you have to mention in `strip_prefix` the root path of the archive file (the first and only root directory in the .zip file). The rules_java has no root directory:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "rules_cc",
    urls = ["file:C:/tmp/b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d.zip"],
    strip_prefix = "rules_cc-b1c40e1de81913a3c40e5948f78719c28152486d",
    sha256 = "d0c573b94a6ef20ef6ff20154a23d0efcb409fb0e1ff0979cec318dfe42f0cdd",
)

http_archive(
    name = "rules_java",
    url = "file:C:/tmp/rules_java-4.0.0.tar.gz",
    sha256 = "34b41ec683e67253043ab1a3d1e8b7c61e4e8edefbcad485381328c934d072fe",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run `bazel fetch //...` to fetch data locally on the machine, which has access to the internet. Then you can just copy prefetched data: from `bazel info output_base` directory on your local PC to `bazel info output_base` in the jenkins job.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work (see update).