# How to deal with MediaPipe Plug in build ERROR

Tags: python, opencv, bazel, mediapipe

I am trying to follow this for a mediapipe plug in in unity. I followed all steps but when i run the command `python build.py build --desktop cpu --include_opencv_libs -v` I get following error. I am unable to understand, can anyone please guide me

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1415]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\HC>pacman -S git patch unzip
warning: git-2.34.1-2 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: patch-2.7.6-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: unzip-6.0-2 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (3) git-2.34.1-2  patch-2.7.6-1  unzip-6.0-2

Total Installed Size:  31.74 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(3/3) checking keys in keyring                                           [#######################################] 100%
(3/3) checking package integrity                                         [#######################################] 100%
(3/3) loading package files                                              [#######################################] 100%
(3/3) checking for file conflicts                                        [#######################################] 100%
(3/3) checking available disk space                                      [#######################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/3) reinstalling git                                                   [#######################################] 100%
(2/3) reinstalling patch                                                 [#######################################] 100%
(3/3) reinstalling unzip                                                 [#######################################] 100%

C:\Users\HC>bazel --version
bazel 4.2.0

C:\Users\HC>set BAZEL_VS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community

C:\Users\HC>set BAZEL_VC=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC

C:\Users\HC>set BAZEL_VC_FULL_VERSION=14.29.30133

C:\Users\HC>set BAZEL_WINSDK_FULL_VERSION=10.0.19041.0

C:\Users\HC>pip install numpy --user
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\hc\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (1.22.1)

C:\Users\HC>python build.py build --desktop cpu --include_opencv_libs -v
python: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\HC\\build.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Users\HC>cd C:\Users\HC\MediaPipeUnityPlugin-master

C:\Users\HC\MediaPipeUnityPlugin-master>set PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C:\Users\HC\MediaPipeUnityPlugin-master\env\Scripts\python.exe

C:\Users\HC\MediaPipeUnityPlugin-master>python build.py build --desktop cpu --include_opencv_libs -v
INFO (build.py): Building protobuf sources...
DEBUG (build.py): Running `bazel --output_user_root C:/_bzl build -c opt --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C://Users//HC//MediaPipeUnityPlugin-master//env//Scripts//python.exe //mediapipe_api:mediapipe_proto_srcs`
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_absl' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_protobuf' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_googletest' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_github_gflags_gflags' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'rules_python' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_rules_apple' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_rules_swift' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_apple_support' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'bazel_skylib' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'pybind11' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/tf_runtime/third_party/cuda/dependencies.bzl:51:10: The following command will download NVIDIA proprietary software. By using the software you agree to comply with the terms of the license agreement that accompanies the software. If you do not agree to the terms of the license agreement, do not use the software.
INFO: Build option --python_path has changed, discarding analysis cache.
DEBUG: Rule 'rules_python' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments shallow_since = "1564776078 -0400"
DEBUG: Repository rules_python instantiated at:
  C:/users/hc/mediapipeunityplugin-master/WORKSPACE:34:23: in <toplevel>
  C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/rules_pkg/deps.bzl:33:10: in rules_pkg_dependencies
  C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/utils.bzl:201:18: in maybe
Repository rule git_repository defined at:
  C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:199:33: in <toplevel>
INFO: SHA256 (https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/master.zip) = 3839996049629e6377abdfd04681ddeeb0cc3db13b9d2ff81bf46700cb4529f7
INFO: Repository rules_cc instantiated at:
  C:/users/hc/mediapipeunityplugin-master/WORKSPACE:78:13: in <toplevel>
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:336:31: in <toplevel>
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'rules_cc':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl", line 111, column 45, in _http_archive_impl
                download_info = ctx.download_and_extract(
Error in download_and_extract: java.io.IOException: Error extracting C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/rules_cc/temp6978268592390816452/master.zip to C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/rules_cc/temp6978268592390816452: Prefix "rules_cc-master" was given, but not found in the archive. Here are possible prefixes for this archive: "rules_cc-main".
ERROR: Error fetching repository: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl", line 111, column 45, in _http_archive_impl
                download_info = ctx.download_and_extract(
Error in download_and_extract: java.io.IOException: Error extracting C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/rules_cc/temp6978268592390816452/master.zip to C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/rules_cc/temp6978268592390816452: Prefix "rules_cc-master" was given, but not found in the archive. Here are possible prefixes for this archive: "rules_cc-main".
INFO: Repository com_google_protobuf instantiated at:
  C:/users/hc/mediapipeunityplugin-master/WORKSPACE:177:13: in <toplevel>
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:336:31: in <toplevel>
ERROR: While resolving toolchains for target @rules_pkg//:build_zip: com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.RepositoryFetchException: no such package '@rules_cc//cc': java.io.IOException: Error extracting C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/rules_cc/temp6978268592390816452/master.zip to C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/rules_cc/temp6978268592390816452: Prefix "rules_cc-master" was given, but not found in the archive. Here are possible prefixes for this archive: "rules_cc-main".
ERROR: Analysis of target '//mediapipe_api:mediapipe_proto_srcs' failed; build aborted: com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.RepositoryFetchException: no such package '@rules_cc//cc': java.io.IOException: Error extracting C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/rules_cc/temp6978268592390816452/master.zip to C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/rules_cc/temp6978268592390816452: Prefix "rules_cc-master" was given, but not found in the archive. Here are possible prefixes for this archive: "rules_cc-main".
INFO: Elapsed time: 17.941s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (3 packages loaded, 11 targets configured)
    currently loading: @bazel_tools//tools/cpp ... (7 packages)
    Fetching ...x4/external/rules_cc; Extracting C:/_bzl/tzoaebx4/external/rules_cc/temp6978268592390816452/master.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HC\MediaPipeUnityPlugin-master\build.py", line 392, in <module>
    Argument().command().run()
  File "C:\Users\HC\MediaPipeUnityPlugin-master\build.py", line 109, in run
    self._run_command(self._build_proto_srcs_commands())
  File "C:\Users\HC\MediaPipeUnityPlugin-master\build.py", line 51, in _run_command
    return subprocess.run(command_list, check=True)
  File "C:\Users\HC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['bazel', '--output_user_root', 'C:/_bzl', 'build', '-c', 'opt', '--action_env', 'PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C://Users//HC//MediaPipeUnityPlugin-master//env//Scripts//python.exe', '//mediapipe_api:mediapipe_proto_srcs']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68104949/build-c-project-with-bazel-offline-without-internet-connection

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your MediaPipe project workspace file is updated with latest Urls in http_archive for rules_cc and others.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31891777)

Comment: Basically, this should be a comment on the post rather than a separate answer. Maybe you could reword it to seem more like an actual answer? As its stated above, an answer should not ask for clarification from the asker.

Comment: Even if you missed to add the corresponding "?", I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."